# Bootstrap modal popup not opening the pop up on link click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a link which I want to open in a modal pop. I'm using Bootstrap 3.

This is my code:

```
<a id="auto-topup2" href="#" data-target="#auto-topup" >
   <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg "></i>
    <?php echo __('Schedule AutoVend', $my_account_info['customerGroup']) ?>
</a>
```

I linked it like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="auto-topup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog aria-labelledby="auto-topup" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="container">
       <!-- Container Code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But its not opening the pop up, whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the data-toggle attribute to your link

```
data-toggle="modal"
```

and then set your href attribute to the id of your modal

```
href="#auto-topup"
```

So you should have something like this

```
<a id="auto-topup2" data-toggle="modal" href="#auto-topup" >
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg "></i>
    <?php echo __('Schedule AutoVend', $my_account_info['customerGroup']) ?>
</a>
```

Comment: No, bootstrap will use the href as your data-target